# Pushing commits to an new branch (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, git, ssh

I have a staging branch and a master branch for my Wordpress site. I recently made a number of commits to the staging branch. I want to pull over the commits from staging to the master and begin adding them to the live site.

What git commands do I need to run on each branch to do so?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506910/git-move-changes-off-of-master-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `master` its a branch based on the `staging` branch, what you want is a merge:

1. Switch to master `git checkout master`
2. merge with `git merge staging`

check [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) for more info.

Comment: git checkout staging &&
git rebase master &&
git checkout master &&
git merge staging